# MySQL - Select last data inserted in last 5 days skip missing records for days

Tags: mysql

I want to select the data that was inserted in the last 5 days, and if the rows are missing for that day then move on to the previous day, but it always have to return rows from the last 5 days.

The column which i'm trying to match is a DATETIME column

I've tried using this query

```
select * from `thum_{ROH}`  where date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY;
```

Now this return data from 2013-12-24 to 2013-12-22 because data on 2013-12-25 and 2013-12-26
is not available.

How can i modify the query to make it return the last 5 days data irrespective of missing rows. So in this case it will return data inserted on

```
2013-12-24
2013-12-23
2013-12-22
2013-12-19
2013-12-12
```

The days which are missing in between the dates above simply have no rows associated with them so they won't be returned.

I have also tried using

```
select distinct(date(date)), power from `thum_{ROH}` limit 5;
```

But this only selects some values in a specific date while skips on the rest. What i mean is that there are around 30 or more rows in each day which are present so the above query only returns around 2 or 3 rows per day.

I hope my question makes sense. I've been trying to find a solution without any success. Please provide any sort of advice on how can i achieve this. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,
Maxx

**EDIT**

Here is the table structure in question.

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| thumType        | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| timestamp       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| rune            | char(15)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date            | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| destruction     | decimal(15,2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| restoration     | decimal(15,2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| conjuration     | decimal(15,2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| alteration      | decimal(15,2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| illusion        | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| power           | decimal(15,2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| magicka         | decimal(15,2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| health          | decimal(15,2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: could you include a description of the table (i.e. columns, types)?

Comment: Does each day only have one row?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the table sturcture in my original quesion.. i've added the table now check the edit section

Comment: @jterry no each day has around 30 to 40 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `join`:

```
select t.*
from `thum_{ROH}` t join
      (select distinct date
       from `thum_{ROH}`
       order by date desc
       limit 5
      ) as date5
      on t.date = date5.date;
```

EIDT:

The above works if we assume that there is no time component.

We can fix that problem by doing:

```
select t.*
from `thum_{ROH}` t join
      (select distinct date(date) as thedate
       from `thum_{ROH}`
       order by date desc
       limit 5
      ) as date5
      on date(t.date) = date5.thedate;
```

Comment: I think you might mean `t.date >= date5.date` but yes this ought to do it.

Comment: @lc.  .  .  . Not exactly.  If there is a time component, then 5 values may not be sufficient.  See the edit.

Comment: Wow works like a charm! I can't thank you enough on how much this helped me. Thanks again . :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 'date' column is of type date, then we can solve this with a subquery to get the 5 most recent non-blank dates and then only select rows from those days.

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE date IN (
    SELECT distinct date FROM tablename ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The column type is datetime so i modified the above query slightly to this                                                   SELECT * FROM `thum_{ROH}` WHERE date(date) IN (SELECT distinct date(date) FROM `thum_{ROH}` ORDER BY date(date) DESC LIMIT 5);        But i'm getting an error saying ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'